# Swing - revalidate() with actionPerformed() problems

Tags: java, swing

I was playing around with swing and i made a login screen but after the user has entered correctly and goes back if he tries to enter with wrong credentials, the warning message show more than 1 time. I think it has something to do with revalite() being in actionPerformed(). Please Help!

this is the class that contains all the GUI:

```
package Login;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class loginScreen implements ActionListener{

JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Welcome");

//login()components
JTextField userName = new JTextField();
JTextField password = new JTextField();
JButton login = new JButton("Login");
//login()components
//welcome()components
JLabel message = new JLabel("Welcome user!");
JButton back = new JButton("Get Back");
//welcome()components
//ArrayLists
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "user1",    "user2"));
ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "pass1", "pass2"));
//ArrayLists

public loginScreen(){

    loginFrame.setSize(200, 180);
    loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    loginFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    loginFrame.add(login());

}
public void refresh(JPanel panel){

    loginFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    loginFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    loginFrame.getContentPane().revalidate();
    //loginFrame.getContentPane().repaint();

}
public boolean testCredentials(String userName, String password){
    boolean isCorrect = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        if (userName.equals(users.get(i))) {
            if (password.equals(passwords.get(i))) {
                isCorrect = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isCorrect;
}
public JPanel login(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(null);

    //userName
    userName.setSize(150, 25);
    userName.setLocation(20, 20);
    //userName
    //password
    password.setSize(150, 25);
    password.setLocation(20, 60);
    //password
    //login
    login.setSize(100, 30);
    login.setLocation(50, 100);
    login.addActionListener(this);
    //login

    panel.add(userName);
    panel.add(password);
    panel.add(login);

    return panel;
}
public JPanel welcome(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(null);

    //message
    message.setSize(100, 30);
    message.setLocation(50, 30);
    //message
    //back
    back.setSize(100, 30);
    back.setLocation(50, 90);
    back.addActionListener(this);
    //back

    panel.add(message);
    panel.add(back);

    return panel;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == login) {
        if (testCredentials(userName.getText(), password.getText()) == true) {
            refresh(welcome());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password!");
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == back) {
        refresh(login());
    }
}
}
```

this class contains the main():

```
package Login;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    loginScreen l = new loginScreen();

}
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Consider using a `CardLayout` instead, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) more details

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 1):

My "suspicion" is, each time you "go back" to the login screen, you are calling the `login` method, which is registering the `loginScreen` as ANOTHER `ActionListener` to the `login` button.

You should isolate your functionality into separate units of work, allowing them to do just the single job they are designed for.

For example, the `loginScreen` shouldn't be making navigation decisions, but should be notifying some kind of observer that the login state has passed/failed and allow it to make the decisions about what it should do in this cases

You might like to take a look at the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because you are adding the same `action listener` everytime you call `refresh`...

You could add the `action listener` just once... like this:

```
public void initialize(){
        login.addActionListener(this);
        back.addActionListener(this);
}
```

and call it after the constructor...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        loginScreen l = new loginScreen();
        l.initialize();
 }
```